# Strange error (the program works right only if i print)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int factor(int n, int k, int v[], int *check){
int i=0;
if (n==1) {
    *check=1;
    return 1;
}
while (i<k && *check!=1){
    if (n%v[i]==0) factor(n/v[i], k, v, check);
    i++;
}
if (*check==1) return 1;
else return 0;
}

int fac(int n, int k, int v[]){
int check;
return factor(n,k,v,&check);
}

int main(){
int i,k, temp;
int P[2]={2,3};
int A[100];
for (i=1; i<20;i++) A[i]=0;
for (i=1; i<20;i++) {
    temp=fac(i,2,P);
    if(temp==1) {/*printf("%d ", temp);*/   A[i]=6; }
}
printf("\n");
for (i=1; i<20;i++) printf("%d ", A[i]);
return 1;
}
```

This function finds the integers <20 that can be expressed as the product of 2 and 3. Factor and fac check if the number can be expressed in that way; in the main i create a vector A in this way: A[i]=0 if i cannot be expressed in that way, A[i]=6 otherwise. The problem is that if i use the commented line the program works right, but if i don't use it, A will be made of only 6s. How is that possible (i think it's corrleated with the pointer argument in factor function, but i'm not sure)?

Comment: Probably undefined behavior lurking somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Problems like this usually mean that there is undefined behaviour somewhere. In order to spot the problem early, always compile with warnings enabled; e.g. if you use GCC, always provide at least `-Wall` flag (and `-O3` often helps to get more warnings, since compiler analyzes the code more thoroughly).

E.g. this is the output when I compile your code:

```
gcc -Wall -O3 my.c
my.c: In function ‘fac’:
my.c:19:7: warning: ‘check’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   int check;
       ^
```

So, as it points out, the variable `check` is left uninitialized. I'm afraid that your intention was to always initialize it with this snippet:

```
  if (n==1) {
    *check=1;
    return 1;
  }
```

But it doesn't work this way: the next time `fac` is called, there is a new local variable `check`, and it's left uninitialized.

I'm not sure the logic in your code is correct, but fixing this undefined behaviour should eliminate the "strange" error which you observe.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot